# Minification of javascript generating incorrect functionality, is my code bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I have the following javascript which works fine in debug, but is failing in production due to improper minification:

```
function buildNotification(config) {

    var notificationWrapper = $('<div>', {
        'id': _.uniqueId('notification_'),
        'class': 'notificationWrapper'
    });

    var notification = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'notification ui-widget ui-state-default'
    });
    notification.addClass(config.notificationClass);
    notification.appendTo(notificationWrapper);

    var notificationList = $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'notificationList'
    }).appendTo(notification);

    //  THIS CODE IS IMPROPERLY MINIFIED: 
    $.each(config.messages, function() {
        $('<li/>', {
            html: this
        }).appendTo(notificationList);
    });

    return notificationWrapper;
}
```

The cuplrit being where I set the list item's HTML markup based on config.

The minified mark-up looks like:

```
function g(a) {
    var b = $("<div>", { id: _.uniqueId("notification_"), "class": "notificationWrapper" }), c = $("<div>", { "class": "notification ui-widget ui-state-default" });
    c.addClass(a.notificationClass);
    c.appendTo(b);
    var d = $("<ul/>", { "class": "notificationList" }).appendTo(c);
    $.each(a.messages, function() { $("<li/>", { html: this }).appendTo(d); });
    return b;
}
```

And here's the error message I receive:

[image]

Could someone drop some knowledge on me? Am I doing something that's bad practice? I ran the code through JSHint, no complaints, and I also have 'use strict' at the top of the file.

**UPDATE:** I experience the same issue when minifying using Google Closure. The code generated by it is:

```
function g(a) {
    var b = $("<div>", { id: _.uniqueId("notification_"), "class": "notificationWrapper" }), c = $("<div>", { "class": "notification ui-widget ui-state-default" });
    c.addClass(a.notificationClass);
    c.appendTo(b);
    var d = $("<ul/>", { "class": "notificationList" }).appendTo(c);
    $.each(a.messages, function() { $("<li/>", { html: this }).appendTo(d); });
    return b;
}
```

This is identical to YUI Compressor.

**UPDATE 2:** http://jscompress.com/ If I compress my file using this software, it works.

The generated code:

```
function r(e) {
    var t = $("<div>", { id: _.uniqueId("notification_"), "class": "notificationWrapper" });
    var n = $("<div>", { "class": "notification ui-widget ui-state-default" });
    n.addClass(e.notificationClass);
    n.appendTo(t);
    var i = $("<ul/>", { "class": "notificationList" }).appendTo(n);
    $.each(e.messages, function() { $("<li/>", { html: this }).appendTo(i); });
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Try to minify with a different tool first, like Google Closure: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: It's part of an existing project with thousands of files. I'm not really comfortable changing minification tools currently. I will compare the minification results though and see if there are differences.

Comment: @EugeneXa I experience the same error with Google Closure.

Comment: Did you try in other web browsers? I think this is a chrome's bug.

Comment: @RicardoGonzales It does not work in the latest FF, either, but other minification tools seem to produce working code... I'm wondering if there is something ambiguous about what I've written. Hmm.

Comment: Is this the first call into jQuery by chance? By looking at the code difference it looks like the breaking difference is putting the two `var` declarations under the same `var`. Maybe it's a jQuery initialisation thing or something.

Comment: Well, it is getting a bit stranger. If I swap out JUST this code block and not the entire file -- it is still broken, but this is where the error is occurring. Hum. I'm going to do some more testing, report back in a bit.

Comment: The actual mistakes are often not where they are reported, because only the symptom will be reported. I.e. if your object is `undefined`, you will get an error accessing a property at the point where you try to access it, even though the actual msitake could have been long before that when they object was incorrectly not populated (just an example, has nothing to do with your code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when looping through `$.each()` -- `this` is expecting / pointing to a jQuery wrapped element. If you have HTML within a string it sees `<i>Test</i>` as:

```
String {0: "<", 1: "i", 2: ">", 3: "T", 4: "e", 5: "s", 6: "t", 7: "<", 8: "/", 9: "i", 10: ">"}
```

Hence giving the error:

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

If you were pointing to a jQuery wrapped element like: `$('#test')`, then `this` would work as intended. But since you are passing a string or array of strings (with HTML in them) you have to use the 2nd parameter of your function `element` to get what you need.

Here is a jsFiddle example: **http://jsfiddle.net/BJBV5/**

```
var messages = $('#test');

$.each(messages, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
    console.log(this); // <-- notice this works as intended
    $("<li/>", { 
        html: this
    }).appendTo('div');
});

var messages = ['<i>Test</i>'];

$.each(messages, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element);
    console.log(this); // <-- notice this will show an array of each letter in the string
    $("<li/>", { 
        html: element
    }).appendTo('div');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I change the offending code snippet from:

```
$.each(config.messages, function () {
    $('<li/>', {
        html: this
    }).appendTo(notificationList);
});
```

to

```
$.each(config.messages, function (index, message) {
    $('<li/>', {
        html: message
    }).appendTo(notificationList);
});
```

The minified code works.

I would be interested in understanding why, but this resolves my issue.